# Outdated Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET when building with Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, windows-10-sdk

When I build my solution locally, the version of Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll is version 10.0.18362.21, but when built on Azure Pipeline it is version 10.0.18362.19.

Does anyone know what needs to change on Azure DevOps to get version 10.0.18362.21 of Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll?

Edit:
The agent is x64 version 2.189.0 running on Windows NT 10.0.19041

Comment: What agent specification are you using in your build pipeline? Also, wouldn't this be solvable by explicitly adding the desired version to your project as a NuGet package?

Comment: The agent is version 2.189.0 running on Windows NT 10.0.19041
It is technically possible to include a specific dll version. My concern with that is this is already an automatic process, and if we introduce a manual process now, then we'll need to remember this next time we need to upgrade the target framework.
Also, won't the automatic process override the manually inserted dll? My thinking is that if the agent is upgraded in some way then the automatic process can remain in-tact.